# service not getting started at boot

Tags: android, service

i have a receiver that starts a service at boot but the receiver never gets fired when at boot

manifest

```
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BatteryService"></service>

    <reciever android:name=".BatteryReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                               
        </intent-filter>

    </reciever>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

why does it not work, everything looks correct

if i open my app the service starts fine

Receiver class

```
    public class BatteryReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        arg0.startService(new Intent(arg0, BatteryService.class));
    }//end onRecieve
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tyzyj,

It looks like you may have misspelled the word `receive` in multiple places as `recieve`.

Try...

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                               
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

unless the class name is misspelled as well?  You may want to post the code for that Receiver class.

Comment: yes i know its spelled wrong by the time i noticed it i already had everything matched up correctly so i didnt bother changing it. receiver code added

Comment: You will still have to fix the misspelling of the <receiver> tags, and you should fix the misspelling of the class to prevent further confusion.