# android : timer : Phone switched off

Tags: android, triggers, timer

I have service running all the time.
I have set some timers to trigger like after a day and week.

But if the device is switched off at the trigger time, when the phone reboots even if timer trigger time has elapsed will the timer trigger or it is lost.

If so how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: No one to answer this query??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but as I understand it, you are trying to handle a long (days or weeks) timer trigger, where the phone may be powered down prior to timer expiration.

As a basic step, you need to ensure that your service is restarted after each power down.  There is advice on doing so in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476705/service-not-getting-started-at-boot).

Your scheduling data will be lost at power down, so you will have to save the information in a persistent file and reschedule on startup.

If your timeline is long enough, you might also consider using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class, which can trigger an application upon expiration of a timer, without polling in the background.

Note, you will still have to reschedule the timer each time the device reboots.